# Possible to force CMake/MSVC to use UTF-8 encoding for source files without a BOM? C4819

Tags: visual-c++, utf-8, cmake, character-encoding

All our source code is valid UTF-8, however some users on Windows cannot build them because their system is configured for a different encoding.

Without adding a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to source files, is it possible to tell MSVC to treat all source as UTF-8, irrespective of the users system encoding?

[See MSDN's link regarding this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173715.aspx) (requires adding BOM header).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can try:

```
add_compile_options("$<$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/utf-8>")
add_compile_options("$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/utf-8>")
```

> By default, Visual Studio detects a byte-order mark to determine if the source file is in an encoded Unicode format, for example, UTF-16 or UTF-8. If no byte-order mark is found, it assumes the source file is encoded using the current user code page, unless you have specified a code page by using `/utf-8` or the `/source-charset` option.

**References**

- [Docs - Visual C++ - ‎Documentation - IDE and Tools - Building - Build Reference: /utf-8 (Set Source and Executable character sets to UTF-8)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8)

Comment: It didn't work, until I figured out that this command has to go before the `add_executable()` command in the `CMakeLists.txt` file

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to create cross-platform code solving the problem using a command-line switch means that

```
add_compile_options("$<$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/utf-8>")
add_compile_options("$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/utf-8>")
```

or adding something like `/utf-8` or `/source-charset` to the `CFLAGs` might mean you'll have to do a similar thing for other platforms, as well.

If possible it therefore might be better to avoid the problem, instead of solving it, by using an `\uxxxx` instead of an unicode character in strings: This way the source specifies which unicode characters to use, but doesn't actually *contain* them.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/utf-8" -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="/utf-8"` into CMake command line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/utf-8")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "/utf-8")
```