# Cyrillic characters are not saved in char16_t under msvc with cmake build

Tags: c++, cmake, utf-16, msvc12, char16-t

I faced the following problem: when I try to save a Cyrillic character in the `char16_t` variable, I get a c2015 error (too many characters in constant). The most interesting thing is that it happens only when I build with MSVC via cmake. If I do it directly through studio, or build with cmake with another compiler, it's ok. Moreover, in the same case, which does not work with MSVC, it is possible to save Cyrillic characters in `wchar_t`. I use version 16 of MSVC generator to generate it.
Example of broken code:

```
char16_t val = u'б';
```

EDIT:
It is trouble with utf literals. I`m use this:
char16_t val = *some_int_val*
And this work correctly. Also, IDE correctly print int value of literal, but on the compile all crushs.

Comment: Please, add to the question post the **exact error message** you got.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: The example I attached at the end is no longer working. Even a trivial assignment to a variable doesn't work, although it should

Comment: Since you are using non-ASCII character in the source code, it is important to check **encoding** of the source **file**. Any modern editor is able to show encoding of the opened file. If the encoding is UTF-8 but without BOM, then make sure you have checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690822/possible-to-force-cmake-msvc-to-use-utf-8-encoding-for-source-files-without-a-bo).